# Is it possible to pass W3C XHTML strict validation and still use Google Analytics code on my webpage?

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to pass W3C XHTML strict validation and still use Google Analytics code on my webpage?

Comment: What errors do you get when you insert google analytics on your page?

Comment: You will probably get better answers at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com. This site is about using existing web apps, not managing your own web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, w3 xhtml strict validation does not check or see Javascript.

Comment: Presumably the `<script>` tags will need to be valid XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

The `<script>` tag in XHTML differs slightly from the one in HTML in that its content is of type `(#PCDATA)`, which means that entities in the tag will be parsed. Thus most non-trivial code will break XHTML validation.

To make your `<script>` tag valid XHTML, use syntax like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
var i=10;
if (i<5) {
    // some code
}
//]]></script>
```